# Can no longuer use our iOS test accounts without assigning a credit car number

Tags: ios, testing, account

Since iOS 8 came out I can no longer use my iOS test accounts to test IAP unless I assigne a valid credit card number to the acccount.

Before iOS 8 came out, I could use these steps to succesfully test IAP with a test accountt that did not have a credit card assigned to the account:

- In OS settings menu, make sure no account is currently logged in for
  app store
- Launch app
- Attempt to purchase an IAP
- Input loggin username and password
- Press continue on prompt that confirms that this is a sandbox account
  and that it wont be charged
- IAP will be triggered   succesfully

I know that if I attempted to loggin with the test account in the iOS settings menu, I would be asked to review the account and assign a credit card to the account. As long as I made sure that no accout was logged in through the iOS settings menu, I could bypass this.

But now since iOS 8 came out, even if I make sure that no accoutn is logged into from the settings menu, when I attempt to purchase an IAP in any of our games, after inputting my account information, I still get the prompt to review the account and I can't complete the reviewing until I input valid credit card number.

We tried with both canadian and US accounts with the same results

Here's my question: Is there any way to use test accounts without assigning a credit card to the account now?

Any information on the subject would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Pascal

Comment: No, this is a new thing. Hopefully it changes.